# Ruby - substitute characters in middle lines?

Tags: ruby, regex

Hi I was reading a textbook about Ruby and found that I can use

```
.sub(/^../,'hello') 
.sub(/..$/,'hello')
```

to substitute the first or the last two characters in the first line.

I was wondering how I can substitute some in other lines if there are multiple lines.

Eg.

```
x = <<end_string
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
end_string
```

to change 'bb' to 'something' or 'cc' to something.

When I tried

```
.sub(/\n^../,'hello')
```

the result was ;

```
aaaHellob
ccc
ddd
```

which changed the first two characters in the second row but somehow the second line was moved to the first line.

So my question is, how can I change(substitute) characters in a certain line?
And if you could explain why I got that result, I would really appreciate it.!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got that result because `sub` replaces the string it matches. Since you matched the newline character (and didn't use one in your replacement text) your string had fewer newlines afterwards.

The simple solution is to use a newline in your replacement text:

```
irb> puts x.gsub(/\n../, "\nHELLO")
aaa
HELLOb
HELLOc
HELLOd
#=> nil
```

If you want to not operate on the last line, you can use a negative lookahead:

```
irb> puts x.gsub(/\n..(?!.*\Z)/, "\nHELLO")
aaa
HELLOb
HELLOc
ddd
#=> nil
```

You could use a positive lookbehind to avoid using a newline in your replacement string

```
irb> puts x.gsub(/(?<=\n)..(?!.*\Z)/, "HELLO")
aaa
HELLOb
HELLOc
ddd
#=> nil
```

The syntax for lookahead and lookbehinds is a little weird, but they just exist to transform patterns (which match and consume some length of the text) into something that matches a zero-width position in the text.  There's already zero-width positional matching in regexes, using:

- `^` for beginning of line
- `$` for end of line
- `\b` for word boundary
- `\A` for beginning of string
- `\Z` for end of string

Lookaheads and lookbehinds just let you define your own:

- `(?=PAT)` ~ match right before PAT
- `(?<=PAT)` ~ match right after PAT
- `(?!PAT)` ~ match anywhere but before PAT
- `(?<!PAT)` ~ match anywhere but after PAT

Answer (score 0):

How about split lines, replace the specific line, and join lines?

```
>> x = <<end_string
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
end_string
>> lines = x.split("\n")
>> lines[1].sub!(/../, 'hello')
>> lines = lines.join("\n")
>> puts lines
aaa
hellob
ccc
ddd
```